# installing logstash 5.5.1 on windows 2012 r2

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I need to make use of logstash as I want to be able to index data residing in SQLServer 2012 tables on a windows 2012 r2 server.

Looking at the following link Installing [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/installing-logstash.html#_yum) there is no reference to installing under windows.

If I go to the bin directory after unpacking the zip I can see a setup.bat file. If I attempt to run this from a Powershell window as administrator nothing happens.

All the demos I've managed to find reference earlier versions of Elasticsearch and logstash at this release it sees to have changed quite a bit.

I already have Elasticsearch 5.5.1 installed and working with Fscrawler for physical documents outside the DB.

Also as an aside to this. For now in terms of an application we are currently using classic asp. so for now I will not be able to use the .Net libraries. to obtain data from Elastic. I was hoping though that I'd be able to get to it via an Ajax call to Elastic.

Comment: If I remember right, to use Logstash on windows, if you have java installed, after unpacking the zip, you just have to run the logstash.bat in the bin folder.

Comment: Regarding your latest point you can get data from elasticsearch with http requests.